# Re-order radio button list based on numerical ordering of radio button value

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

I have pricing options for variations listed as radio buttons on my woocommerce site. The issue is I didn't upload the products in price order from least to greatest which is what I want. I'm hoping I could create a fairly simple hack with jquery to re-order the radio button options to be in price order from least to greatest. I know how to inject some script into my site, I'm just not good enough with js yet to write it. Any direction would be awesome. Here is a product page sample: http://181.224.136.218/~savann39/?product=boss-multi-drain

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any chance you can wrap your options (input + text + pricespan) in a tag with some sort of class? Also it would be nice to have the $ symbol outside the pricing span and for it a class too

Comment: I will check on that asap. I'm sure I can though... just in the middle of a move..